# ASP.NET Form Authentication: RoleProvider Configuration Exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, config

I implemented custom membership and role provider in my MVC4 web app, which utilizes forms authentication. I followed [Matt Wrock](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx)'s implementation, but I'm receiving the config error below.

At first I thought it might be that the `type` variable was not fully qualified, but that was not the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### **Configuration Error**

**Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message:** Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 27:       <providers>
Line 28:         <clear />
Line 29:         <add name="AdminRoleProvider" type="MyProject.Common.Security.AdminRoleProvider" />
Line 30:       </providers>
Line 31:     </roleManager>
```

Source File: C:\Dev\MyProject\web.config    Line: 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

The `AdminRoleProvider` threw an error upon invocation. The exception was swallowed and merely displayed as a "Configuration Error".